# Creating Visual Studio extension package installer

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have created a Visual Studio extension that is compatible with Visual Studio versions 2005 - 2013. For VS2010 and later I've just uploaded the extension in vsix format to the gallery and to be honest I want to keep the comfortable vsix format for these newer versions of VS. My problem is that I want to publish the extension for legacy VS versions (2005 and 2008) as well and I haven't found a clean solution to my problem despite spending several days with research.

What I've done so far:

- I've found out that pre-VS2010 VS versions made use of msi installers to get the job done and many people created msi installers that work for both pre- and post VS2010 VS versions. (Note: I don't want msi isntaller for VS2010 and later, there vsix is OK for me).
- Checked out wix and read some docs/examples, it can create msi installers from vsix but the details are still not clear for me...
- I've never created complex msi installer that detect installation paths etc... I've spent at least 2 days by testing out the features of a test msi installer project in VS2005 and VS2008. To me this msi creation process seems to be quite error prone and I don't know the pitfalls of creating msi for extensions.
- I've examined the manual installation steps that have to be performed to deploy an extension for VS2005 and VS2008 (registry modifications, post-executing devenv, ...)

Questions:

- I want to keep the vsix format for VS2010 and later - can I distribute an msi on the Visual Studio Gallery page for VS2005 and VS2008 using the same extension guid I used for VS2010 and later? Is this possible or a single guid is allowed only in case of distributing a single msi for all versions?
- How does the Visual Studio gallery page extract the extension id/guid from the msi? (The gallery page does this without problems in case of a vsix package).
- If I use wix to create an msi from vsix can it deal with both VS2005 and VS2008 using a single msi? (This is important, especially when someone has both versions on his machine...)
- If I decide to create my own msi (for example by creating an installer project in VS) then what are the most important restrictions/requirements to meet in order to get a valid extension installer msi? (extra requirements for the msi installer of a VS extension compared to the installer of any other regular software).
- I've tried to find a simple msi extension installer project example among opensource software sources using google but I wasn't successful, can you point at an example to "copy-paste"?
- I was thinking about creating a simple custom installer in C# that performs the manual installation steps. Could I upload this into the Visual Studio gallery? (I guess not...)

Any comments/suggestions are welcome especially if you have already faced a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from my own experience, I developed several packages with VS 2005-2013 support. I use Wix generating .msi that copies files and writes to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\x.0. Supporting only VS 2005/2008 from an .msi should be even more simple.

Visual Studio gallery doesn't extract anything from msi (you can even just post a link to your site). I don't have links to good samples, but basically you need to add info about your package to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Packages plus Menus and [ToolWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166406%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you use wix as simple msi creation tool or as a vsix-to-msi converter? As a converter I haven't seen any options for multi-vs-version support (it may be implicit though). From what you said I could upload the VS2005-8 version of the plugin with the same id/guid to the gallery if it doesn't parses the installer but the gallery page links make use of the guid of the package (at least for vsix). What will be the link of my VS2005-8 extension?

Comment: I use wix as a simple msi creation tool, I didn't try the vsix-to-msi converter. I don't know how gallery uses the guid of the package, I thought links for extensions are random.